# Need applescript for clear cookie on MAC for Safari 8 browser

Tags: applescript

I need to perform below things using applescript.

- Launch Safari,
- click "Clear History and Website Data" on Safari menu bar,
- click "Clear History" button,
- close safari browser.

I have tried with below code:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate 
tell application "System Events"
  click menu item "Clear History and Website Data…" of menu "Safari" of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1 of application process "Safari"
  delay 1
  click button "Clear History" of pop up "Safari"
  quit
end tell
```

Comment: Does not look like code at all o_0

Comment: What problem(s) are you having with this code?  Please be as complete & precise as possible

Comment: Here problem is not able to click "Clear History" button, getting error on step: click button "Clear History" of pop up "Safari"

Comment: _refer this screenshot for safari 8 clear cookies applescript_: [link](http://snag.gy/Gbs7Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Safari" to activate  
set frontmost to true  
tell application "System Events"  
    tell process "Safari"  
        set frontmost to true  
        click menu item "Clear History…" of menu "History" of menu bar 1  
        delay 3  
        click button "Clear History" of sheet 1 of window 1  
    end tell  
end tell  
tell application "Safari" to quit
```